# How to change a global variable within a callback function using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to change the value of a global integer variable in a callback function of a button. It lets me print the variable but not change it? How can I change its value within that callback function?

Comment: Put `global NameOfMyVariable` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.